# PHP Fails to Execute, IIS 10, PHP 7

Tags: php, iis

I have followed some videos and seen some questions on here to no avail.

I have installed IIS (using windows 10) and downloaded PHP 7 along with Microsoft visual as stated to do so on a few tutorials. Also I installed the CGI which is a visible Icon on my IIS.
I then went into Handler Mapping and created a new module and entered the request path as '*.php' and  selected FastCgiModule,  to which I choose entered the Executable to the folder where the Php files I download are located and selected the PHP CGI(C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe).
I have a file named index.php and inside the file I have "Hello" and phpinfo() function in the file.

However, when I view the page it shows the text "Hello "but its not executing the PHP Code (`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`).

Any advice as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you viewing the `index.php`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: Hi,

I'm viewing via WIndows Edge browser via Browse Website in IIS

Comment: As `http://localhost/index.php`? (I think it'd be localhost).

Comment: Sorry I just realised that I have 2 files one is called index.php and one is called index.html.

Both contain the same information "Hello" and the phpinfo(); function.
So the index.html display only 'Hello' and the index.php shows the HTTP 404 error.

I just want to be able to execute Php
And Yes its http://localhost/index.php and http://localhost/index.html

Comment: You should update the question with that information. The `.html` not executing the PHP code is expected behavior. This also is sounding more like a server issue then a coding issue; might wanna try serverfault.

Comment: @chris85 Please don't send people to post questions on off-topic sites. [SF] does not accept questions about personal workstations and development environments.

Comment: @MichaelHampton `managing the hardware or software of servers` sounds exactly what this user is asking -http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @chris85 That's not what's going on here.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is Install and Configure PHP on my IIS. And as I said i followed tutorials such as 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAHZKR7ULjI 
And for some reason does not work?